# BatchGetItem returning successful but null

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, async-await

Trying to run a BatchGetItem from Lambda to DynamoDB however When I run the query it returns a null response and logs no issues. **PK** (Primary Key) and **SK** (Sort Key) do exist in the table and the values associated with each are currently stored in the table as seen below. The Lambda function has permissions to run BatchGetItem on that specific table and when I run a single GetItem on that same table it works fine and returns a single item. Any help with trying to get BatchGetItem to return the queried items would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

#### DynamoDB Image

[image: DynamoDB Attributes]

#### Lambda Code

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

// Create DynamoDB service object
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var info;

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  var params = {
    RequestItems: {
      "candidates": {
        Keys: [
          {
            "PK": {S: "jack"},
            "SK": {S: "C108951642"}
          },
          {
            "PK": {S: "ben"},
            "SK": {S: "C143956179"}
          },
          {
            "PK": {S: "hill"},
            "SK": {S: "C268283233"}
          }
        ],
        ProjectionExpression: "Name"
      }
    }
  };
  
  ddb.batchGetItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      data.Responses.TABLE_NAME.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        console.log(element);
        info = element;
      });
    }
  });
  return info;
}
```

#### Lambda Response

```
Test Event Name
batch

Response
null

Function Logs
START RequestId: a411114a-29b9-4f7f-bc20-2a5caff9f0cf Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: a411114a-29b9-4f7f-bc20-2a5caff9f0cf
REPORT RequestId: a411114a-29b9-4f7f-bc20-2a5caff9f0cf  Duration: 442.11 ms Billed Duration: 443 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 78 MB

Request ID
a411114a-29b9-4f7f-bc20-2a5caff9f0cf
```

Comment: The `BatchGetItem` *API call* returns something. The `batchGetItem` method returns nothing, ever, you pass it a callback function which is eventually invoked. You `return info` before that callback function is called and before `info` is set to anything.

Comment: This is really a javascript question. Use `await ddb.batchGetItem(params).promise()` instead of the callback.